# How to place specific constraints on the parameters of a Pydantic model?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

How can I place specific constraints on the parameters of a Pydantic model? In particular, I would like:

- `start_date` must be at least `"2019-01-01"`
- `end_date` must be greater than `start_date`
- `code` must be one and only one of the values ​​in the set
- `cluster` must be one and only one of the values ​​in the set

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Set
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


class Query(BaseModel):
    start_date: str
    end_date: str
    code: Set[str] = {
        "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4",
        "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5",
        "Y1", "Y2", "Y3"
    }
    cluster: Set[str] = {"C1", "C2", "C3"}

@app.post("/")
async def read_table(query: Query):
    return {"msg": query}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pydantic has a [set of constrained types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#constrained-types) that allows you to define specific constraints on values.

### start_date must be at least "2019-01-01"

```py
>>> class Foo(BaseModel):
...   d: condate(ge=datetime.date.fromisoformat('2019-01-01')

>>> Foo(d=datetime.date.fromisoformat('2018-01-12'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
d
  ensure this value is greater than or equal to 2019-01-01 (type=value_error.number.not_ge; limit_value=2019-01-01)

>>> Foo(d=datetime.date.fromisoformat('2020-01-12'))
Foo(d=datetime.date(2020, 1, 12))
```

### end_date must be greater than start_date

For more complicated rules, [you can use a root validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#root-validators):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from datetime import date

class StartEnd(BaseModel):
    start: date
    end: date
    
    @root_validator
    def validate_dates(cls, values):
        if values['start'] > values['end']:
            raise ValueError('start is after end')
            
        return values
        

StartEnd(start=date.fromisoformat('2023-01-01'), end=date.fromisoformat('2022-01-01'))
```

Gives:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for StartEnd
__root__
  start is after end (type=value_error)
```

### For code and cluster, you can [use an Enum instead](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#enums-and-choices)

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from enum import Enum  # StrEnum in 3.11+


class ClusterEnum(str, Enum):
    C1 = "C1"
    C2 = "C2" 
    C3 = "C3"
    

class ClusterVal(BaseModel):
    cluster: ClusterEnum
        

print(ClusterVal(cluster='C3').cluster.value)
# outputs C3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very clear. The only thing I didn't quite understand is how to write the Pydantic `Query` model following the constraints you put. Specifically, I'm guessing it's like: `class Query: start_date: ?; end_date: ?; code: CodeEnum; cluster: ClusterEnum` but I don't know how to handle the dates knowing that the user will make the POST call by passing them as strings.

Comment: You can just define them as `start_date: date, end_date: date`, Pydantic will automagically convert an iso-formatted string (`YYYY-mm-dd`) to a date object for you and validate it. `StartEnd(start='2023-01-01', end='2024-01-01')`.

Comment: So you put the date control in the `Query` class? `@root_validator \n def validate_dates(cls, values): if values["start_date"] < datetime.strptime("2019-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date(): raise ValueError("Error1"); if values["start_date"] > values["end_date"]: raise ValueError("Error2"); return values`

Comment: Correct, I'm guessing it's the query you want to validate - an end_date before a start_date doesn't seem like a valid query. I'd use the `condate` field type to validate the start date (if possible, it was added in a relatively recent version of pydantic) instead of doing it in the root validator. The root validator should generally implement more advanced validations that can't be performed by the field type itself (since definitions in the field type can be used for documentation, is clearer when being read, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Enum` class or a `Literal` to validate the code and cluster and then use a `root_validator` for the date. Also type hint the date field with datetime instead of a string `str`. Like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

"""using Literal to validater the code and cluster"""

class Query(BaseModel):
    start_date: datetime
    end_date: datetime
    code: Literal[
        "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3"
    ]
    cluster: Literal["C1", "C2", "C3"]

    @root_validator()
    def validate_dates(cls, values):
        if datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1) < values.get("start_date"):
            raise ValueError("Date cannot be earlier than 2019-01-01")

        if values.get("end_date") < values.get("start_date"):
            raise ValueError("end date cannot be earlier than start date")

        return values
```

if you wish to use `Enum` to validate the code and the cluster you will define the `Enum` class like so

```
class Cluster(Enum):
    C1 = "C1"
    C2 = "C3"
    C3 = "C3"


class Code(Enum):
    A1 = "A1"
    A2 = "A2"
    A3 = "A3"
    A4 = "A4"
    X1 = "X1"
    X2 = "X2"
    X3 = "X3"
    X4 = "X4"
    X5 = "X5"
    Y1 = "Y1"
    Y2 = "Y2"
    Y3 = "Y3"
```

and then replace the literals in the Query class with this

```
code: Code
cluster: Cluster
```